# Filtering out values from readonly tuple type

Tags: typescript

I'm having some trouble writing a helper type that takes a tuple of `Parser<T>` as argument and returns a tuple type of the `T`s except when `T` is `undefined`.

Here is what I have so far :

```
class Parser<T> {}

type ToSequenceValueType<P extends ReadonlyArray<Parser<any>>> =
    P extends [infer P, ...infer R]
    ? P extends Parser<infer V>
      ? V extends undefined
        ? ToSequenceValueType<R>
        : [V, ...ToSequenceValueType<R>]
      : never
    : []

type A = readonly [Parser<number>, Parser<string>, Parser<undefined>, Parser<boolean>]

type R = ToSequenceValueType<A> // Should be [number, string, boolean]
```

But the recursive calls (`ToSequenceValueType<R>`) are underlined as an error and it reads :

```
Type 'R' does not satisfy the constraint 'readonly Parser<any>[]'
```

How should I do ?

[Link to playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEAKYCcIFMEB4AqA%20aBvAvgFCEAuAngA7LQYD2AysgI4CuyAdsMgGpghsZKyNLGjIAHiQ4ATGACVkYabXYgyAQQQIwZEYhTow7MllPQAvIWjW4YyTJgBtAJbsAZqjgAaaADp-rh4I0HIAulY2APy2ElLssnD6qGiBntxYETbQ0dx2cQks8chursjSmVnZNAzMbJw8fAJCaHIZlTYAXNCO3D7%20vnSMrBxcvPzIglQtWOHtXezIAG6oFV2O4aRC0OoW0AiKyqpk3fBIyewsALYARqhYPqcGaBAkCK4A5veJZ%20iF0sWlaRfR7Ja60WggRTsGbEchUEK7Qa1EYNcaTYTqLBAA)

Comment: You could do [either of these](https://tsplay.dev/WvpR3N) but your code has unrelated problems; [empty generic object types act strangely](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-doesnt-type-inference-work-on-this-interface-interface-foot--) and are passing in a `ReadonlyArray` to something that expects an `Array`, so your output is not right; even if you fix those, you are apparently unintentionally [distributing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) unions.  Could you fix these issues before I write up an answer?

Comment: So I replaced the array destructuring part with `P extends readonly [infer P, ...infer R]` and solved the distributivity problem with `[V] extends [undefined]`, and it seems to work as intended even with en empty generic class. What I don't understand is that destructuring a ReadonlyArray doesn't provide an element and a ReadonlyArray rest...

Comment: Because `any[]` extends `readonly any[]` but not vice versa. I’m confused about what the question is; could you pare it down to a [mcve] where the only issue is the one you’re asking about?  I thought it was the recursive type not being allowed, but now it seems like something about `readonly`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are looking for this solution:

```js
class Parser<T> { }

/**
 * I'm using square brackets for [Val] to avoid distributivity
 */
type MapPredicate<T> =
  T extends Parser<infer Val>
  ? [Val] extends [undefined]
  ? []
  : [Val]
  : never;

type Mapped<
  Arr extends ReadonlyArray<Parser<any>>,
  Cache extends ReadonlyArray<unknown> = readonly []
  > =
  /**
   * If argument is empty array - return empty array
   */
  Arr extends readonly []
  ? readonly []
  /**
   * This should be the last call of recursion
   * I just adding last element of an array to Cache
   */
  : Arr extends readonly [infer H]
  ? [...Cache, ...MapPredicate<H>]
  /**
   * If array contains more than one element
   * I call Mapped with Tail (all elements but the first)
   * an adding first element (Head) to cache
   */
  : Arr extends readonly [infer Head, ...infer Tail]
  ? Tail extends ReadonlyArray<Parser<any>>
  ? Mapped<[...Tail], [...Cache, ...MapPredicate<Head>]>
  : never
  : Cache;


type P = Parser<number>;


type A = readonly [Parser<number>, Parser<string>, Parser<undefined>, Parser<boolean>]

type R = Mapped<A> // [number, string, boolean]
```

Because you want to call `ToSequenceValueType` recursively -> `P` not always will extend `[infer P, ...infer R]`, last two calls it will extend empty array and array with one element.

More information/explanation and examples about tuples you can find in [my blog](https://catchts.com/tuples#map)

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEAKYCcIFMEB4AqA+aBvaAvgFBED0AVOUdOdAJIDkAttAK4QCWAdgObQQBHVomTQARgjDAA1sgAuMAGYB7BNADaANTAgAutDnLoYAG7KOAE2gWOEOQg5jWcjiY5yAntXKkingA6iALJg-rAIyDbAYHLImDgAvNTQGNDIAB6xXBYw8EioaNyKqNDaIFjJAPwaZfoZWTkarNnIityRulUandDQAFw1Oj390FzIJqgA3CQBwaGBFmjJAIIIavXI2TAASshgFspcIB6rkh5oeSjoYFweWFgANMkAwlIAFqIbW9C7+4fHpzA52a0i4ygA7lxEtAIn8jh5uslEskKFRejR6IpjAgeKwmJs5NBbGkmP5PNiztAALQw+SsBBcElkhGIM7JGi+XqnNKZTaNWEHeGI3rVAX-BHqYao9m0DBvYkQN7KVggKxiURyD7QcB2aDREAgaDKLERYD0ziHGX0aAAK3YhP2Nl42sghOQIGQ+K4hONxkZrKBBiMr2AHxlnJG3K+-L2guOGiKJQAEsNquoAHSZkMfB7QTPpkJhCJRGJxJNYKWUK10LEBhHAQ5yMDcGBMVQat43I1jNIer1yat6nSGwsLaDg9xvFLNw0ACmHvc9BJgTkJmtEbSQcgAlFau47uHxN7r3UvvdBZ0nY9ug0PQ8hw8kBlHed8xUL1Im1Ff9rn81-pw4PQugwGceQaHZY3FQFzkuAobjuCoRWgUdIjQDNM1AoDdFzDD02zZA-0zQtwkiDholiNAfwsCskJGMYJgQJ9oAI6YZg8QI4GgBI4EQK40C4PF1QQLA2L8DjRGWbjaTheN1Dg9BBKYYTHl4-J0DsBxeFUhS0GaCxWnaGjc10sRlGUD0bgrdjOO2aTUMWZYcFIUgNCU4Tc00w9czMiy9i4XQgA)

If `MapPredicate<H>` returns empty array `[]`, `...MapPredicate<H>` evaluates to nothing, that is how I filter `undefined` values